# Detuned oscillators seem to bounce against each other

Tags: web-audio-api

**Note: If you click on the fiddle, ensure your sound is turned down to a minimum.**

I'm using the Web Audio API and I want to detune one oscillator against another by a few cents to create a thicker sound. The problem is when I do detune one oscillator it creates a pulsating sound. If i play with the detune amount it gets better or worse depending on the values I set for each oscillator. If I detune one oscillator by -1 (as shown in the example below) the sound coming back from the oscillators cuts out periodically.

Why is this? Software synths I've used before allow you to detune by single cents so assuming that isn't the issue.

```
// create web audio api context
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

// create Oscillator node
var oscillator = audioCtx.createOscillator();

oscillator.type = 'square';
oscillator.frequency.setValueAtTime(440, audioCtx.currentTime); // value in hertz
oscillator.connect(audioCtx.destination);


// create Oscillator node
var oscillator1 = audioCtx.createOscillator();

oscillator1.type = 'square';
oscillator1.frequency.setValueAtTime(440, audioCtx.currentTime); // value in hertz
oscillator1.detune.setValueAtTime(-1, audioCtx.currentTime);
oscillator1.connect(audioCtx.destination);

oscillator.start();
oscillator1.start();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c1xdnLtm/

Comment: This isn't a software issue, it's how interference between signals close in frequency works: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the underlying issue is in understanding of Physics, not computer programming.

Comment: Hmm interesting. Thanks Ben. As I mentioned software synths such as reasons subtractor allow you to detune by a single cent without the beat effect. Perhaps thr subtractor compensates for that somehow